# Soundness and completeness of Fitch-style for first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am looking for literature in which a detailled proof of the soundness and completeness of Fitch-style proofs for first order logic is given. In his 1952 book "Symbolic Logic, An Introduction" he proves that the system is free from contradiction, but I could not find any resources in which the soundness and completeness of the system for first order logic is proven (or even stated). If someone here knows where to find any such literature, it would help me a lot.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You cannot find in the book because there is no semantics... Having said that, the soundness proof is quite easy: you have to check that each rule is truth-preseving.

Comment: You can use some Natural Deduction textbook, like e.g. [Chiswell & Hodges](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jacques.jayez/Cours/Proving/Mathematical_Logic_(Ian_Chiswell,_Wilfrid_Hodges).pdf).

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA for your response. I did not expect to find a proof of completeness in Fitch's original book, but I was expecting to find it somewhere else, since Fitch notation seems to be used frequently for proving first order statements (e.g. here https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/). Since people have translated from FOL to Fitch (i.e. they introduced some semantics), I thought some soundness and completeness proof would be around _somewhere_ :)